# How can I make Ubuntu route all traffic through my Wireguard VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have set up a working Wireguard VPN server remotely. I have confirmed that this VPN server works, as my phone can connect flawlessly with it.

In Ubuntu 23.10, I have imported my `*.conf` file as follows:

```
$ nmcli connection import type wireguard file remote-server.conf
```

I can see my VPN connection in the right upper hand networking menu, and it also appears when running:

```
$ nmcli connection show
NAME              UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE 
netplan-enp5s0    (redacted)                            ethernet   enp5s0 
remote-server     (redacted)                            wireguard  wg0    
lo                (redacted)                            loopback   lo
```

However, when turning on this connection by toggling it in the right upper hand menu, all my network traffic seems to disregard this VPN connection and go through my regular internet connection. I have confirmed this by looking up my external IP address.

How can I make Ubuntu route all traffic through my Wireguard VPN?

By the way, this is my `remote-server.conf` file:

```
$ cat remote-server.conf 
[Interface]
PrivateKey = (key)
Address = ipv4/24,ipv6/64
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = (key)
PresharedKey = (key)
Endpoint = url:port
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, 192.168.1.0/24, ::0/0
```